# How is Url.Action picking routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have these 2 routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "First",
    url: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Second",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

The route handling works ok but the url generation does not work fine in all  cases.

I'm trying to use the @Url.Action("Index"):

- when I'm on "Home/List" it generates "Home/Index"
- when I'm on "Home/1/Edit" it generates "Home/1/Index"

I can see a pattern here, but I don't know why it generates the urls like this, I would like to have the second form only when I explicitly pass in the "id" parameter.

I can use the following to solve my problem, but I'm not so excited about passing in route names:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("Second", new { action = "Index" })
```

Is there anything else I can do to have the helper work as expected?

Comment: You probably mean "I would like to have the **first** form only when I explicitly pass in the "id" segment". Am i right?

Comment: Well, right now, with the helper I don't have control over which form is generated. I want to have the **second** form only when I pass in the "id" parameter to the helper because (to me) that's the only case when it makes sense. Right now it is inferring it from the currently rendered view.

Comment: Just curious. Isn't the default schema {controller}{action}{id} better? Then it should redirect you to index from /home/edit/1

Comment: Pf didn't try with the schema you mentioned (it could work). I would really like to stick with the one I mentioned. It's also the schema StackOverflow has and I like it a lot.